# Rails - how to load Google Maps in a partial (through AJAX)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-maps, partial-views

I spent couple last hours figuring how to load Google Maps through AJAX.
I have a simple AJAX link like this (it's a view):

```
<%= link_to "Load Car Info", car_info_path(car.id), :remote => true %>
<div id="car_info"></div>
```

In `car_info.js.erb`, I render the partial:

```
$("#car_info").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => '/cars/car_info', :locals => {:car => @car}) %>");
```

And beside all accessible data stored in the `@car` variable, there's also this code:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
  </script>
  ... other text, data from @car ...
```

The map is never rendered.

Is loaded in the header of the HTML document.

I tried to include this line into the partial, but the `#map` was still empty.
I also tried to put the JS code for Google Maps to the `car_info.js.erb` file, but still - the map is not rendered (also, there's no error message).

When I take the code for rendering the map out of the partial and place it to the regular static page (view), it's rendered properly.

How to render the map from a partial?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

I just tested if Google maps is properly loaded in the partial

```
  if (window.google) {
    alert('Loaded');
  } else {
    alert('Not loaded');
  }
```

And it seems to be loaded.